# Type forwarding from referenced assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have to move a class from one assembly to another as part of an update for an application already shipped to users. Moving the class generates problems with serialization - which is needed for DB storage.

I have two projects, `A.csproj` and `B.csproj`, and `A` holds a reference to `B`. The class `MyClass` sits on project `B` and I need to move it to project `A`.

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/type-forwarding-in-the-common-language-runtime) .NET supports type forwarding for the opposite case (moving stuff from `A` to `B`, since the old project needs to reference the new) by using the [TypeForwardedToAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.typeforwardedtoattribute?view=netframework-4.8).
For a case like mine [TypeForwardedFromAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.typeforwardedfromattribute?view=netframework-4.8) seems to be the solution - but no.

I guess that the attribute works fine when just using the class. Nevertheless the application is unable to deserialize data containing `MyClass` from the DB, as the class was saved along with the assembly it came from - `B`, and won't recognize it as the same class in `A`.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: What type of db application/library are you using?

Comment: SQL database, updated via ElasticSearch. For serialization of this class we use MessagePack.

Comment: Ok you have to know that even if you move the type to another assembly it wont work. If the assembly path is also saved then it have to use that assembly. You could load the require assembly dynamicly as i did that one time, but its really a complicated and hard to work with. So for better understand of your problem show us how the data is saved and also some code we can check. and also the library your are using to extract the data from the db

Comment: What ends up getting stored in the DB field? Is it .NET binary serialization? JSON? Something proprietary?